# Django and DRF How to use the fields of a POST request to the API before saving?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have an installation of Django 1.10 and Django REST framework.

I am getting POST requests well, but I would like it before the content is created, doing some tasks with the fields, I have the following in my views.py file

```
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route
from rest_framework import serializers
from suds.client import Client
import base64
from . import views

# Create your views here.

from cfdipanel.models import Report, Invoice, UserProfile
from cfdi.serializers import ReportSerializer, InvoiceSerializer, UserProfileSerializer


class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Report.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def set_invoice(self, request, pk=None):

        #get report object
        my_report = self.get_object()
        serializer = InvoiceSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(report=my_report)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And this a fragment of my file serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from cfdipanel.models import Report, Invoice, UserProfile

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'karma')


class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = ('uuid', 're', 'rr', 'tt',
                  'emision_date', 'type_invoice', 'status', 'owner')


class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserProfileSerializer(read_only=True)
    ownerId = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(write_only=True,
                                                 queryset=UserProfile.objects.all(),
                                                 source='owner')
    invoices = InvoiceSerializer(many=True,
                                 read_only=True,
                                 source='invoice_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'body', 'owner', 'ownerId', 'invoices')
```

And this other is a snippet of models.py

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    emision_date = models.CharField(max_length=28)
    re = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    rr = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    type_invoice = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    tt = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=9,
                                default=Decimal(0))
    def __str__(self):
        return self.uuid
```

The status field comes empty, to fill it I want to do something similar to the following code in view.py before the fields are saved:

```
url = 'https://an-api.com/ConsultService.svc?wsdl'
client = Client(url)
string = "?re=" + re + "&rr=" + rr + \
             "&tt=" + tt + "&id=" + uuid

response = client.service.Consulta(string)

# Create content for field status
status = response.Status
```

And after you get the response from the webservice then save and create the Invoice content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.data`returns a `dict` instance, and `InvoiceSerializer` returns an `Invoice` "instance", so you can modify the data before of after deserializing it. using:

```
data = request.data
data['field'] = 'foo'
```

or

```
serializer = InvoiceSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.object.invoice_field = 'foo'
```

for DRF 3

```
serializer = InvoiceSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.save(invoice_field ='foo')
```

Comment: Show error: `AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable`

Comment: the problem is used header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` delete header and work fine!!

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

Try to print `request.data`

You can access the each field send via request using `request.data['keyName']` it will print the value send in key called keyName.so that you can manupulate the request and then sent it to serializer.

Comment: print `request.data`
`<QueryDict: {'------WebKitFormBoundaryxzOtd3tWkoWOdACG\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data': [''], ' name': ['"owner"\r\n\r\n2\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryxzOtd3tWkoWOdACG\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data', '"uuid"\r\n\r\n72DB605A-CCD1-4FA5-96ED-C8E8A22258D7\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryxzOtd3tWkoWOdACG\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data', '"re"\r\n\r\nAER990218E83\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryxzOtd3tWkoWOdACG\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data', '"rr"\r\n\r\nOFF151023V9A\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryxzOtd3tWkoWOdACG\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data', ` and more ....

Comment: @laur , so now you can access any data using data['keyName'] you want and manipulate it before passing to the serializer.

Comment: `print (data['uuid'])` y show `raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'uuid'"`

Comment: sorry I think inside name everything is in character so first just serialize th request.data properly then try to access it.

Comment: Do you advise me to access the data after serializing?
`print (['name']['uuid'])` show `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: @Piyush-s-wanare the problem is used header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` delete header and work fine!!